# PowerShell: Populate a Table from 2 Objects, and THEN Sort

Tags: powershell

First of all, here is what I have right now:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController
ForEach ($dc in $dcs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server $dc.HostName -Properties Name,Enabled,LastLogon | sort -Property LastLogon | select-object Name,Enabled,@{Name="Last Logged In"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')}},@{Name="Domain Controller"; Expression={$dc.Name}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

This will go to Domain Controller #1, spit out a table of every user and their last logon time, and then sorts that table by last logon time. Then it does this again for Domain Controller #2 in a second table, and so on. What I really want, is a single table with all of this information, which I can then sort by the user Name.

But, I think what I really want is something that gathers all of this information, and then returns only the most recent logon times for each user. So, for example, User A may have logged in most recently to Domain Controller #1, and User B most recently logged into Domain Controller #3, so I would only need to see that information in a table, sorted by last known logon time.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You could do a look up on each domain controller spit that into separate tables then compare the date time for last login for each user and take the latest one and spit that into a new table for each user with the same info

Answer (score 0):

better yet here you go... It grabs all your domain controllers. then grabs all your users. It loops through each user and gets the last logon on each domain controller into a temp array and sorts by date and selects that last one.  Then adds each user and last logon to the lastLogon array.  It does this for all users before spitting out the lastLogon array which has all your info and only the last logon timestamp and the domain controller that was logged into.

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -filter *
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | select samaccountname
$lastLogon = @()
ForEach ($user in $users) {
$temp = @()
    foreach ($dc in $dcs)
    {
    $temp += Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Server $dc.HostName -Properties Name,Enabled,LastLogon | sort -Property LastLogon | select-object Name,Enabled,@{Name="Last Logged In"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')}},@{Name="Domain Controller"; Expression={$dc.Name}}
    }
    $lastLogon += $temp | Sort-Object 'Last Logged In' | Select-Object -last 1
}
$lastLogon | ft
```

Expected output:

```
Name  Enabled  Last Logged In  Dommain Controller
user1 True     2014-08-28      DC1
user2 True     2014-08-27      DC2
```